# Type has no properties in common with type 'ColumnType<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am writing an app with react and ant design

I want to use antd table

but it does not show my data

Code

```
const ListOfProperties = () => {
  const columns = [
    {
      type: "Type",
      state: "State",
      location: "Location",
    },
  ];
  const properties = [
    {
      type: "Flat",
      state: "Anambra",
      location: "Udoka",
    },
    {
      type: "Flat",
      state: "Anambra",
      location: "Udoka",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Skeleton active loading={loading}>
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={properties} />
    </Skeleton>
  );
};

export default ListOfProperties;
```

I created an array of objects which I passed to the data source and columns to the columns

as stated in the docs

but I am getting error

Error

`Type '{ type: string; state: string; location: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'ColumnType<any>'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide `title`, `dataIndex` and `key`. Always look it up in the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/) first.

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Type",
    dataIndex: "type",
    key: "type"
  },
  {
    title: "State",
    dataIndex: "state",
    key: "state"
  },
    {
    title: "Location",
    dataIndex: "location",
    key: "location"
  },
 ];
```